# how to use mongoose populate/ref like this?

Tags: mongodb

I'm tring to find every sensor(according to sensor_id) infomation.
the sensor_id is related _id.

my code is:

```
//this is vnodeInfo
      var vnodesSchema = new Schema({
                "_id": {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId    //this is ref sensor_id
                },
                "node_id": {
                    type: String
                },
                "name": String,
                "sensors": [
                    {
                        "sensor_id": {
                            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                            ref: "sensors"
                        },
                        "name": String,
                        "alias": String
                    }
                ]
            });



    //this is sensorsInfo
     var sensorsSchema = new Schema({
            "_id": {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId    //this is link
            },
            "node_id": {
                type: String,
                ref: "Nodes"
            },
            "order": String,
            "name": String,
            "alias": String,
            "low_limit": {
                type: Number
            },
            "high_limit": {
                type: Number
            },
            "value": {
                type: Number
            },
            "state": String,
            "last_update": {
                type: Date, default: Date.now
            }
        });
```

this is my statics method:
I'm tring use sensor.sensor_id related to sensorSchema
"sensor_id==_id" use this ref to get sensors's infomation

```
findSensorsById: function (vnodeId,callback) {  
    //use sensors.sensor_id to get sensorinfo  
    //this is a static method.
             return this.findById(vnodeId).populate('sensors.sensor_id').exec(callback)    
                    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your code?

Comment: I want to ref a Array to Array;